# Runtime error while running go code

Tags: go

I am trying to run a simple golang code

```
$ cat blah.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("sudo","ls")
        out, err := cmd.Output()
        fmt.Printf("%s", string(out))
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
}
```

I am getting:

```
$ go run blah.go
    blah.go
    utils.go
    weave_help_test.go
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x400dc1]

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    runtime.panic(0x4b32a0, 0x5b1fc8)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6
    main.main()
        /home/Abhishek/go/src/github.com/blah.go:12 +0x1c1
    exit status 2
```

How should I debug it?

```
$ go version
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64
```

Comment: You should check error returned by cmd.Output before using its result.

Comment: Thanks, works after the error check!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error object returned from the running the command is nil (which is good! that means it succeeded!). But you are accessing `err.Error()` which on a nil object would result in just that panic.

So

a. check if err is nil

b. you can just print it, no need to call `err.Error()`

i.e. your code should look like this:

```
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error running command:", err)
       return
       //or even panic here
    }
    // we only get here if err is nil
    fmt.Printf("%s", string(out))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Rookie mistake on my part :)